# Find minimum velocity needed to reach a given coordinate?

Tags: math, game-physics

I am coding a simulation of ball movement. I have an updateBall function which runs every 100 miliseconds to update the location of the ball.

How could i find out the minimum velocity needed to reach a given target coordinate?
Below is the relevant code,

```
ball.x = 0;
ball.y = 0;

targetX = 100;
targetY = 200;

friction = 0.03;

dx = targetX - ball.x;
dy = targetY - ball.y;
distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
velocity = ?;

// runs every 100ms
updateBall()
{
  ball.x += velocity;
  ball.y += velocity;

  velocity -= friction;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems wrong that you apply `friction` to both components separately - in this case ball can stop vertically but move horizontally - looks strange, doesn't it?

Is is worth to apply acceleration to velocity vector. Seems you have straight moving - so you can precalculate coeffients for both components.

Concerning needed velocity:

```
distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
v_final = v0 - a * t = 0        so   t = v0 / a
distance = v0 * t - a * t^2 / 2      substitute t and get
distance = v0^2 / (2a)        
  and finally initial velocity to provide moving at distance
v0 = sqrt(2*distance*a)
```

where `a` is acceleration proportional to your `friction` accordingly to elementary interval `dt` (100 ms ).

```
friction = a * dt
a = friction / dt

v0.x = v0 * dx / distance = v0 * coefX
v0.y = v0 * dy / distance = v0 * coefY
```

at every stage you update `v` value and get components

```
v = v - friction
v.x = v * coefX
v.y = v * coefY
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes it's wrong using two separate velocity for x and y, I have edited to use a single velocity now. From my understanding, v0 = sqrt(2*distance*a) is the formula and the value of v0 is what I need right? How do i get acceleration's value, a=?

Comment: Yes, you wanted v0. I added formula for acceleration a (note it is more general parameter than friction - if you change time interval, moving remains the same with the same a)